# Rubber gem having issue with graphite server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am having an issue with using `rubber`, whenever I try `cap rubber:bootstrap` and had a staging instance, it always stuck on this error.

```
* executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'cd /mnt/localstore-production/releases/20120519213905 && RUBBER_ENV=production RAILS_ENV=production ./script/rubber config  --force --file=\"role/graphite_server\"'"
    servers: ["production.localstore.com"]
    [production.localstore.com] executing command
 ** [out :: production.localstore.com] Instance not found for host: ip-10-2-118-252
 ** [out :: production.localstore.com] 
    command finished in 5849ms
failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\''  bash -l -c '\\''cd /mnt/localstore-production/releases/20120519213905 && RUBBER_ENV=production RAILS_ENV=production ./script/rubber config  --force --file=\"role/graphite_server\"'\\'''" on production.localstore.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue was that I changed the static IP of the instance from the AWS Console, so why the host info of the instance changed some how.

So I use this command `cap rubber:referesh` to refresh every thing and then bootstrap the instance and it solved my problem.